# How to mock a hash with string keys in rspec which comes from a webservice in the new hash notation of ruby

Tags: ruby, web-services, hash, rspec, notation

When i got an response from a webservice which return a hash with string keys, i have to read them like this:

```
foo = @web_service.get_foo
if foo["code"] == 200
  # do something
end
```

In the rspec i have to mock this webservice and return a hash of string, because i check for a string key "code".

```
@web_service.should_receive(:get_foo).and_return("code" => 200)
```

But how do i this with the new ruby hash notation. Something like:

```
@web_service.should_receive(:get_foo).and_return("code": 200)
```

I cant change the response in the service to a symbol key.
Have I to live with the mix of old and new notation?

**EDIT**
I change a word in the Topic. It is a hash with string keys.

Answer (score 0):

If the hash is a string key, you're not able to use the new notation. Only with symbols.

In the case that you'd really like to access using symbols, one option is to import Rails [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) and use their [Indifferent Access](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb) functions. It adds another dependency to manage, but can help keep your code cleaner too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your web service returns JSON. You can let the parser convert the keys to symbols:

```
require 'multi_json'
MultiJson.load('{"code":200}', symbolize_keys: true)
# => {:code=>200}
```

This would allow you to change your code to

```
foo = @web_service.get_foo
if foo[:code] == 200
  # do something
end
```

And your spec to

```
@web_service.should_receive(:get_foo).and_return(code: 200)
```

Comment: It is not working, because it is a hash with string keys and not a string

Comment: Did you implement `get_foo` or is it provided by a gem/library?

Comment: provided by a library. I cant make changes there

Comment: In that case, I would write a simple [wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for that library and change the output as needed, i.e. symbolize the keys.